# pycharm states i'm missing 1 required positional required argument 'year'

Tags: python

when I attempt to *inherit* my parent class *Car* into my *child* class using *super()*, it states I am missing one required positional argument which is year. any idea why this could be happening?

```
class Car:
   """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

   def __init__(self, make, model, year):
       self.make = make
       self.model = model
       self.year = year
       self.odometer_reading = 0


class ElectricCar(Car):
   """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

   def __init__(self, make, model, year):
       """Initialize attributes of the parent class."""
       super().__init__(make, model, year)


my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla' 'model s', 2019)
```

Comment: `'tesla', 'model s'`. You are missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your class and functions work perfectly fine but you forgot to add **comma** on your second last line of code where you provide you values

```
my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
```

if you comment last two lines of code it can't show any error.

Comment: thanks for the much needed help, you are awesome